# UITab bar Contorller

Tags: uitabbarcontroller

I am new to iphone app development.  I have created a simple app based in tab bar controller.

In my app I have 4 tab bar item, all of them loading view from XIB file. Everything works fine.

But my problem is my first tab item is name **home**, it contains 2 buttons in its view, if buttons are tapped a new sub view loaded from xib file.

At this moment if user select Second tab bar item which named **product info** and then again select first tab bar item (**home**) my app displays only sub views  of first tab item (**home**) not the main view or super view of first tab item(**home**).

How do i get main view or super view every time when first tab item (**home**) is selected?

please give me some idea..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got it. I use the bellow codes in .m file:

```
(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated]; 
    [subView removeFromSuperview]; // hide all sub views
    // My custom code here
}
```

Thanks